# WIX Bootstrapper with individual upgraded msi won't uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an wix bootstrapper that installs multiple msi's via chaining. One for the main app and others for plugins for the main application. The plugins version separately and their MSI could be upgraded during an autoupdate routine. The problem I have is that the uninstall on the bundle wont uninstall the MSIs for the plugins once they have been upgraded. Is it possible to set it up so that uninstalling the bootstrapper will uninstall the plugins regardless if they were upgraded?

For reference, I am always doing a major upgrade on each MSI.

Comment: how did you solved this problems in WIX ? Thanks and waiting for you reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a chained MSI is upgraded outside of the control of the WIX bootstrapper, un-installing the WIX bootstrapper will leave the upgraded MSI behind.  This is by design.  See the answer to [How Wix bootstrapper uninstall msi package that has been upgraded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322253/how-wix-bootstrapper-uninstall-msi-package-that-has-been-upgraded/) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I determined the same thing after further investigation. Our final solution is going to be to upgrade the bootstrapper after a change to any given plugin or host application. The upgrade should leave unchanged msi(s) from the previous versions and upgrade the changed msi(s). This will allow the uninstall to always remove all plugins and the host.